# How can I toggle sibling child elements?

Tags: jquery, toggle

I want to be able to click an item and toggle its classes.  This is working as expected. Also, when the item is clicked a child element's class toggles (in order to hide with CSS). This is working as expected.

I want to click any sibling to one of these items and have the others' classes toggle.  This is working as expected. Here is where I am stuck: I want to be able to click an item and have the sibling's child element's class toggle - this is NOT working as I had hoped.

I've used some help articles to get this far using jquery, but my newb knowledge isn't getting me all of the way there.

This codepen has the HTML and JS that I'm trying flush out: https://codepen.io/deejmer/pen/zgRYyj

```
$(".feature-expand a.card").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().toggleClass( "col-12").toggleClass( "col-md-6");
    $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass( "col-12").addClass("col-md-6");
    $(this).find(".hidden-item").toggleClass( "shown");
});
```

Thanks in advance for helping a jquery newb!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just *all* hidden elements except this one.

```
let thisHiddenItem = $(this).find(".hidden-item");
$('.hidden-item').not(thisHiddenItem).removeClass('shown');
thisHiddenItem.toggleClass("shown");
```

**[Demo](https://codepen.io/isherwood/pen/dxdoyp?editors=1010)**

If necessary, limit scope by targeting the containing feature element:

```
$(this).closest('.some-wrapper-el').find('.hidden-item').removeClass('shown');
```

Protip: You can combine your class toggler: `.toggleClass( "col-12 col-md-6")`

Comment: After testing I decided the UX isn't right so had to take a different approach, but now the same issue plagues me. :-(  Is it best to follow on this conversation if I have a slightly new need, or start a new question?  Basically it should behave mostly the same way, just as popovers now instead of expanding areas.  It works as expected if one clicks the same element on and off.  The problem comes again when I want to click a sibling element and have all other reset.  Forked pen: https://codepen.io/deejmer/pen/ZgrZoj  I did my best to reverse engineer what you provided before, but failed.

Comment: No one downvoted my answer. There's one on your question, though (where I commented).

Comment: If you're going to revise your question heavily, just remove the accept on this answer. Might be better to post anew, though.

Comment: Thank you, I assumed that might be the best approach.  You answered this one so let's not take that away for someone who needs a similar use case.  I've opened this new question since it is different: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57397847/how-to-toggle-sibling-elements-and-related-children-properly